# REST endpoint design for retrieving results in many to many relationship

Tags: rest, api, many-to-many, relationship, restful-url

I have read many of the other posts on designing many to many relationships restfully; however, i couldn't quite found the answers i was looking for.

Basically, I have 2 tables in the database and another many-to-many table that bridges these 2 tables. 
For simplicity lets call them:

- Course(CourseID, CourseName)
- Instructor(InstructorID, InstructorName)
- CourseInstructor(CourseID, InstructorID, lectureRoomName) (MANY-TO-MANY)

I have 2 questions:

1) How should I get all the entries inside the CourseInstructor table.

Is `GET /courses/instructors` correct? (or `GET /instructors/courses` or both)

Or should I have a seperate endpoint called /coursesinstructors

2) Also I want to be able to get all rows in the CourseInstructor table by passing in CourseName.

Normally i think i would do, `/courses?name=coursename` if i was searching for a course. And, I might use the endpoint `/courses/{courseId}/instructors/{instructorId}` to search for a specific entry in the many-to-many table.

Thus, I am curious would something like this work: `/courses?name=coursename/instructors` (Is this even possible?)

Another alternative is to have another endpoint called `/coursesinstructors` and i can make `/courseinstructor?name=coursename` to get the results.

Or should i make 2 calls to get the results by doing:
- get the id through `/courses?name=coursename`
- and follow it with `courses/{id}/instructors`

I am open to any other suggestions and solutions other than the ones I came up with above (not sure mine are correct solutions anyways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first scenario, it really depends on what your use cases are. `GET /courses/instructors` would imply (only) retrieving the instructors, so I'd personally go with just `GET /courses`, and [embed](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/rest-ep2/embedded-resources) the instructors.

As for the second scenario, `/courses?name=coursename` should be good enough (plus `/courses/{courseId}/instructors/{instructorId}` for drilling down to a specific entry). The 2 calls is another valid option. However, an URL like `/courses?name=coursename/instructors` doesn't seem to be valid, according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out that the url I showed is invalid due to RFC 3986.

Comment: I am new to designing REST api's and have never embed other resources before. I am definitely going to read the article you attached. So, now I know I can embed instructors, but what if i wanted to get courses in another case without any extra instructor information. If i want to have just course information at some point wouldn't that extra instructor information embedded going to be redundant (or unauthorized if i want to only allow admin to pull the information about course - instructor relation).

Comment: you could easily control that through a header/parameter (something like `/courses?includeInstructors=true`), doubled by role (admin) validation

Answer (score 1):

If you really do need (1), a full dump of all course-instructor pairings, then I think your best bet is to support

```
GET /course-instructors
GET /course-instructors?courseName=whatever
```

You can then either link to or embed the course and the instructor.

```
{
    "course": "/courses/12",
    "instructor": "/instructors/54"
}

{
    "course": {
        "name": "Political Science",
        ...
    },
    "instructor": {
        "name": "Hober Mallow",
        ...
    }
}
```

What you return depends on the needs of your clients. Perhaps you return abbreviated information plus a link to the full representation, or perhaps it's ok to return just the links because courses and instructors are (should be!) highly cacheable.

As an aside, I think you'd be well-served to stop thinking about how the database stores data, and rather think about what clients need from your API.

Comment: Yes, I really need to dump all pairings and i started to feel like it would be best for me to have /course-instructors. But having that raises another question for me; my course-instructors m2m table has no courseinstructorid since lectureID, courseID, roomName combine for the primary key. Thus i cant support /course-instructors/3, would that break my restful design (not having access to a single resource from an endpoint); though, I can always do /course-instructors?lectureid=5&courseid=2... Would that be allright?

Comment: And what about supporting the endpoint /course/{courseid}/instructor/{instructorid}? Now that I have the end point /course-instructors, is it good to keep access from other endpoints to the same resource, or should I do all operations related to course-instructor relation through this /course-instructors endpoint?

Comment: As a side note, as you have indicated, I am trying to stop thinking about how database stores data and provide a better API for my clients needs. However, this is my first API design, thus im a bit confused. In my initial design, I had a different endpoint for every single table in my database; indeed, im trying to stop thinking in terms of how database stores data.

Comment: @Perex19 You'd be keying in by course name, which is hopefully unique. I would not support access to specific instructors under the course, no.